# Jenkins Blueocean - Repo level setting not available

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

**Jenkins Pipeline:** Setup Jenkins and added blue ocean plugin as per the documentation. Added my GitHub org during the new pipeline set up and it created the repo jobs (I had Jenkins file on a couple of the repositories) automatically. Everything looks perfect and great..

**ISSUE: Repo Level configuration missing:** I can configure ('Configure') the organization level job settings in Jenkins and save it.. but on the repository level, only 'View configuration' option shows up. I'm unable to edit repo job configurations.

I want to have few separate configurations for repositories under the organization. How do I get this? or what am I doing wrong?